# jaxb2 goal is not generating classes

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, spring-boot

In my Spring SOAP web service when I run

```
mvn eclipse:eclipse
```

I get an exception:

```
A required class was missing while executing org.codehaus.mojo:jaxb2-maven-plugin:2.2:xjc: com/sun/codemodel/CodeWriter*.
```

I tried some fixes without succcess:

1) Checking if jars downloaded correctly (file sizes)

2) Adding jdk path in eclipse.ini.

I'm unsure however about removing references to JRE in Eclipse in favor of JDK as some posts suggest. Will this not affect some of my apps that depend on JRE? Do I remove JRE configuration at Eclipse level or in the Java installation directory? My `disburse.xsd` has:

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
    xmlns:tns="http://www.onewallet.com/webservices/disburse/generated"
           targetNamespace="http://www.onewallet.com/webservices/disburse/generated" elementFormDefault="qualified">     
     <xs:element name="getAllDisbursementsRequest">
        <xs:complexType/>
    </xs:element>    
    <xs:element name="getAllDisbursementsResponse">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="disburseInfo" type="tns:disburseInfo" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>   
    <xs:complexType name="serviceStatus">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="statusCode" type="xs:string"/>
            <xs:element name="message" type="xs:string"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>     
</xs:schema>
```

My `pom.xml` has:

```
      <plugins>
          <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
              </plugin>
          <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb2-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.1</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>xjc-schema</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>xjc</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <sources>
                          <source>src/main/resources/xsds</source>
                        </sources>
                        <packageName>webservices.disburse.generated</packageName>
                <clearOutputDir>false</clearOutputDir>
            </configuration>
          </plugin>
      </plugins>
```

All dependencies have red underlining in the above POM. Two issues:

a)I want to know how I can be able to resolve this exception so I generate Java classes

b)I also want to know how I can retrieve the data from a specific MySql table using JPA/Spring Data. The [example](https://www.concretepage.com/spring-boot/spring-boot-soap-web-service-example) I am following here uses a database with only one table schema.

Comment: Please specify the versions of the tools you use.

Comment: Spring Boot 1.5.9,Eclipse Oxygen, jre 1.8, wsdl4j Ver 1.6.3, jaxb-api 2.3.0. I'm connecting to MySQL 5.5.

Comment: Specifically Eclipse Oxygen.3a Release (4.7.3a).Build id: 20180405-1200

Comment: Another thing, you use JRE, but you must be using JDK for java development. Can you replace it? For example, according to this [comment](https://github.com/highsource/maven-jaxb2-plugin/issues/69#issuecomment-257149509) **you must use a JDK to launch Eclipse**.